# Trying to understand a Python line code

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to python, and when I search for a way to get a string length without using "len()", I found this answer:

```
sum([1 for _ in "your string goes here"])
```

Can someone help me understand this line,what's the '1' doing there for example?

Comment: google "python list comprehension" and read the docs for the `sum` function, and you should be able to answer this yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically equivalent to this:

```
lst = []
for dontCareAboutTheName in "your string goes here":
    lst.append(1)
print(sum(lst))
```

The list comprehension basically collects the number `1` for each character it finds while looping through the string. So the list will contain exactly as many elements as the length of the string. And since all those list elements are 1, when calculating the sum of all those elements, you end up with the length of the string.